# How to detect sounds

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-recording

I never worked with Core Audio on iOS, but now I need to detect clap sounds coming from the mic. So.. where should I start? Are there any libs just for that (audio analyze)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Music-DSP](http://www.musicdsp.org/index.php) has quite a bit of DSP code for you to peruse.  It is extremely unlikely you'll find a turnkey solution for doing this with Core Audio.  From a very high level you'll need to install a render callback using RemoteIO for microphone input, and then analyze the incoming audio to detect the claps.  I'm far from a DSP expert so I can't say what algorithm would work best for you.  Amplitude detection would be the simplest but other options would include beat detection or envelope followers.